# Url rewrite not working -- displays a blank page. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am porting a project where we want to rewrite the URLs using Mapfiles. It was written in ASP.NET webforms and used Helicon ISAPI for the URL rewrite
The MapFile has a simple structure (.txt):

```
<Product-url1> <sku1>
<Product-url2> <sku2>
<Product-url3> <sku3>
```

The idea is that if the URL is in particular pattern (/product/ as an example) it should rewrite the URL as /productpage?Sku=

With that in mind, I wrote a custom RewriteOptions by implementing the IRule interface as follows

```
public class ProductPageRequests : IRule
    {
        public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;            
    
            string pattern = "products/(.+)\\.aspx";
            Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match match = r.Match(request.Path);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                //response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
                context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = "ProductPage?SKU=1234" + request.QueryString;
                return;
                
    
               
                request.Path = "/ProductPage?SKU=1234";
                request.Host = new HostString("localhost:5000");
               context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
                return;
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    
                app.UseWebOptimizer();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseSession();
    
                app.ConfigureStackifyLogging(Configuration); //This is for Stackify logging
                loggerFactory.AddStackify(); //add the provider
    
                app.ConfigureStackifyLogging(Configuration); 
    
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                });
                var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .Add(new ProductPageRequests());
                app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

**What has been tried**

1. /productpage works fine
2. when I go to /products/test1.aspx  the ProductPageRequests ApplyRule method is hit. The pattern matches and it gets in the if (match.success) statement
3. Trying with either response.Headers or request.Path is not working -- the /productpage is not even hit (I have set breakpoints to see if the razor page is hit)
4. I have tried to use the full path (e.g. http://localhost/productpage?SKU=1234  in both the headers and request.path locations
5. In all cases, there is a blank page served when the ApplyRule is hit
6. I have tried this with even a static page (/test.html which works in the browser but when used in the headers or request.path serves a blank page), so not sure the issue is because of Razor pages

What am I doing wrong? Have been struggling with this for a day now. Is it the sequence of where the RewriteOptions is in the Startup.cs?
I have searched for anything related to custom IRule implementation and did not see anyone having this issue - please help!

Comment: Have you tried to use the out-of-the-box rewrite rules instead of using a custom implementation? Are the real world requirements more complicated than the sample? If not, you could try to use `.AddRedirect("products/(.*)\\.aspx", "ProductsPage?SKU=$1")` as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#when-to-use-url-rewriting-middleware You can use browser DevTools to check the status code that is returned by the redirection when you browse to `/products/*`. It should be between 300 and 399 (most likely 301 or 302)

Comment: Thanks for the response -- the issue is I want to use the mapfile, where in the URL will be mapped to a SKU.
Using .AddRedirect("products/(.*)\\.aspx", "ProductsPage?SKU=$1") will map the SKU to the incoming URL

e.g. for /products/test1.aspx I want to rewrite to ProductsPage?SKU=skufortest1
with the above, it will rewrite to ProductsPage?SKU=test1